# Unable to get value of the property 'transports' - SignalR

Tags: signalr

I'm using signalr in my asp.net web forms application, all seems to work good, except that I'm getting exception on the line

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

However, if I click no on "Do you want to Debug" popup, signalr functionality works pretty well. The full error message is this

> Unable to get value of the property 'transports': object is null or undefined

And here is complete js code

```
var docStatusUpdate = $.connection.docstatus;

    docStatusUpdate.statusUpdate = function (msg, session) {
        var sessionId = $('input#sessionValue').val();
        if (sessionId == session) {
            $("#statusUpdateMsgContainer").text(msg);
        }
    };

    docStatusUpdate.endProcessing = function (session) {

        var sessionId = $('input#sessionValue').val();

        if (sessionId == session) {
            $('input[id*=btnRefresh]').click();
        }
    };

    $.connection.hub.start();

    function assignValues() {}
```

I'm using Asp.net 4.0, signalr is installed via nuget.
Any ideas how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a discussion on http://jabbr.net regarding to this issue, and it turned out, that none of the suggestions work. The main thing was to make sure that jQuery library isn't referenced more than once. Anyways, I just deleted browser data, and it started to work as expected.